# Converting all void functions to non-void function

Tags: c++, function, void

I think, it is better to return an integer even if the function does not actually return anything. 
The returned values can be used to reflect various error conditions inside the function. Is there any price we pay for by always opting an integer return function rather than a "void" function in C++?

Comment: Yes, it is. It is called readability.

Comment: I don't have a canonical answer to give, but this is a terrible idea. How do you tell the difference between a "void" function and a function returning `int`? It would make the readability of your code much worse, and violates the [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) rule.

Comment: What's to downvote here? The idea may be wrong, but this isn't meta where votes indicates agreement.

Comment: @Angew: I absolutely agree. Please don't downvote on grounds of an idea being a poor one.

Comment: @Angew, Bathsheba - I downvoted because I felt the question to be (a) primarily opinion based and (b) doesn't, in my opinion, match a [topic that can be asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If anything, it's better suited to http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @KarlNicoll Both would be perfectly fine reasons to vote to *close.* For downvoting, I'm less certain (although everyone's free to vote as they wish).

Answer (score 9):

You'll have the computational overhead of having to return a value from every function. But a good optimiser might remove redundant return values.

It's bad idea as it will make your code unreadable. But it's a bad idea for another reason: it creates yet another possibility for undefined behaviour to creep into your program. Aside from `main`, all functions marked `int` *must* return an `int` on *all* control paths.

Why not use the exception mechanism; which is the idiomatic way?

Answer (score 6):

If you have a design policy that **every** function should return a code that tells you whether it succeeded, then changing `void` functions to return such a value makes sense. You end up passing output parameters by reference instead of returning values, and you get code that doesn't look like idiomatic C++. But if it's only functions that would otherwise return nothing, it's just an arbitrary change and will confuse people to no end.

If a function cannot do what it's supposed to do it should throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there would be a price attached. We'd be paying the price of creating code which is less clear and more error-prone.

First off, returning a raw `int` would be a *terrible* idea. How do you differentiate between a function whose `int` return type is an actual integer, and one whose `int` return type is an error code?

But even if you returened an `int`-sized, `int`-like `ErrorCode` type instead, it's still a bad idea. You now have a lot of functions in your hands which claim they can result in an error. The question is, what errors are possible? In theory, every call site should check for all possible errors, if not to handle them then to pass them on.

In practice, this will have one of two consequences. Either people follow through with this, and every piece of functionality code will be swamped with error-handling.

Or (more likely) people just resign and ignore the returned error codes, possibly with comments like `// this cannot fail`. This, however, gives you a false sense of security. When writing the function, you "safely" return an error code and assume it will be handled. The caller will however most likely happily ignore it.

In C++, if you want to let the caller know there's been an error, you should use the buil-in error mechanism: *exceptions.* These cannot be ignored by the caller without deliberate effort on their part, and allow you to write code which cares only about errors interesting for it.